# Is there a way in Bibdesk to erase wrong completion suggestions due to typing mistakes?

Tags: auto-completion, bibdesk

For example, if I type once Shakespere instead of Shakespeare Bigdesk keep suggesting it when I type Sha in the Author field. Is it a way of cleaning up the list of such suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Quit and relaunch BibDesk and the problem will go away. The autocompletion database is generated from existing names in the document, plus anything else you added to a particular field (or field type) since the last time you launched the program.