# BibDesk: Where are previous entries in bibtex fields stored internally?

Tags: bibtex, bibdesk, macos

I am using **BibDesk V1.8.8** on **High Sierra** without any troubles.

I have added a custom BibTeX field `note` (type textual) in every `bibtex` entry. Clicking on the entry in the database a new window opens and I can edit all fields.

My question is the following: when I want to add e.g. a note in the field `note` **BibDesk** remembers all previously entered notes/informations. Where are these previously entered notes stored?

Is there a way to modify/delete these notes?

Comment: A clarification re: "when I want to add e.g. a note in the field note BibDesk remembers all previously entered notes/informations." Do you mean the **auto-complete suggestions** that pop up (or rather drop down) when you type into an empty field? On that, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391281/ (from 2017): "The autocompletion database is generated from existing names in the document, plus anything else you added to a particular field (or field type) since the last time you launched the program." So for the most part, you can't purge that list, as long as the entries exist in your file.

Comment: @marquinho: yes, I meant **auto-complete suggestions**. You have answered my question: reading the link it is suggested to restart BibDesk and that builds up the auto-complete suggestions based on the content in the Database. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/391281/) explanation by one of the maintainers (from September 2017),

> The autocompletion database is generated from existing names in the document, plus anything else you added to a particular field (or field type) since the last time you launched the program.

This means that the autocompletion suggestions in the drop-down menu are *only in part* based on a *purgeable* history log. This part is reset when you close the session.

*The non-purgeable part* consists of all the existing entries in your `.bib` file. This part will keep popping up as long as the entries exist.

The above description is consistent with my experience with the current version, although since 2017, there has been an update to "improve auto-complete of text" (per the [release notes of v1.6.15](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bibdesk/files/BibDesk/BibDesk-1.6.15/) from May 2018).
It appears that the basic mechanism was not affected by the update.